# How can I bold/Italic/Size title of a bar chart in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

I am not able change the size, font and bold/italic in spotfire.
I tried many ways but didn't got it.

Comment: Judging the quality of the Q/As you posted to this site: please make sure your questions adhere to the norms as stated in [ask]. This question shows no research, needs at least a picture to show what you want to achieve and preferably your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change that by using the properties section.
Right click on the chart and take properties.
Properties ->Fonts ->Decription.

Comment: When posting self-Q/As, at least make the answer clear, e.g. in this case by adding images with the buttons explained.